# How to compute the maximum of a function?

Tags: function, fortran, max

How to compute the maximum of a smooth function defined on [a,b] in Fortran ? 
For simplicity, a polynomial function.

The background is that almost all numerical flux(a concept in numerical PDE) involves computing the maximum of certain function over an interval [a,b].

Comment: See Numerical Recipes in Fortran http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookfpdf.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1-D problem with smooth and readily-computed derivatives, use [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Minimization_and_maximization_problems) to find zeros of the first derivative.

For multiple dimensions, and readily-computed derivatives, you're better off using a method that approximates the Hessian. There are several methods of this type, but I've found the [L-BFGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) method to be reliable and efficient. There a convenient, [BSD-licensed package](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/lbfgs.html) provided by a group at Northwestern University. There's also quite a bit of well-tested code at http://www.netlib.org/

Comment: Thank you! Quite comprehensive!

Comment: I tried the package provided by Northwestern Univ., but it did not work well enough. I used it to minimize sin(x) over [-1,5], whose result of course should be -1. Setting the initial value of x = 1, I got the minimum -0.8xxxx and the point was -1. It can be seen that the package found a LOCAL minimum instead of a GLOBAL one. Finding a global minimum is a common difficulty for people researching optimization, but I think people designing the package SHOULD correctly solve the problem I posed because right derivative of sin(x) at -1 is far from ZERO.

Comment: @booksee: All gradient-based minimizers are local. In fact, most minimizers are local. Global optimization is an NP-complete problem. Also, sin(-1) is not a minimum. Sine extrema occur at sin((n+1)pi/2). Moreover, all sine local minima are global minima. The fact that you're stopping at something other than -pi/2 (about -1.6) suggests that your function or its derivative has a bug.

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood my opinion or I didn't state it clearly enough.-_-... I mean the package produced the following results: in [-1,5] min_sin(x)= -0.8xxx when x=-1, while the TRUTH should be min_sin(x) = -1 when x=1.5*pi approximately 4.712, which belongs to [-1,5]. I hope they could put more initial searching points, distributed uniformly in the interval, to avoid producing the problem I described.

Comment: @booksee: Gradient minimizers start from one initial searching point, and search for a local minimum.  *The user* can start them from additional searching points, but selecting a good starting point requires some knowledge of the function, and the minimizer has no such knowledge.  If you're truly looking for a global minimizers, consider a [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or other heuristic approach.